# Docker and ram usage

Tags: java, docker, ram, swarm

I have a swarm cluster with 24Gb of RAM on each nodes.

Free -g shows 6Gb used but I get some OutMemory errors on some java or elasticsearch containers.

> ```
>               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
>
> Mem:             23           6           6           0          10          16
>
> Swap:             1           0           1
> ```

I removed all reservation or limits on containers

Any idea what causes the OutOfMermory ? I did set Xmx on the containers and they are not using to much RAM...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it the JVM or the operating system that thinks it is out of memory?

Comment: The JVM, the OS seems fine

Comment: Newer versions of Java respects the docker environment when deciding default JVM values including memory.

Comment: I've been able to give limits to java and it worked. My biggest issue with this is that only 25% of the RAM is used and still I get OutOfMemory errors.

Comment: If the JVM gives out of memory exceptions then assign more RAM to the JVM.

Comment: I already have same applications running with the same JVM settings. We had that on an other cluster and we had to add more RAM to the OS to be able to run more stacks. Do you know if setting limits is acting like reservations and doen't allow to use more RAM than the "limit" setting ? I removed them all but I am wondering the effect of limits.

Comment: Sorry, no, not yet.  I would suggest monitor ram usage over time to see if you have a memory leak first.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was a kernel configuration in the sysctl.conf.

I had this :

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf |grep vm.
vm.swappiness=10
vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.dirty_ratio=2
vm.dirty_background_ratio=1
```

I removed everything setted for DB2 (put back the default configuration) and now I can take advantage of all the RAM of the hosts.

I kept this :

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf |grep vm.
vm.swappiness=10
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Thanks